# Ping but no internet

Tags: browser, internet-connection

Today when I switched on my computer I was faced with a very sad problem. No internet.

I tried disconnecting and reconnecting the router. Switching it on and off again. But no avail. I have tried ping and tracert both of which are working normally and hence I am certain that there is no connection problem in the cable or such but strangely my web browsers are unable to connect web pages. Which is getting depressing. Any help would be very nice. Thanks

Comment: Did you try pinging an IP address or a domain?

Comment: What is your LAN config, what system you use? Did you set dns? Do you use proxy? Did you try other browser?

Comment: Have you checked with some other machines.

Comment: Sounds like a domain issue. Try changing your router's settings to use Google's domain or something similar.

Comment: Did you ping a machine on your local network or a remote machine?